# Java - Read in 7 integers, count number of reoccurrances

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am taking an intro Java class and I'm stuck on an assignment. The goal is to write a program using single dimensional arrays that reads in 7 integers and then displays the number of times each value entered reoccurs (i.e. if you enter the number 12 twice, one of the output lines is "Number 12 occurs 2 times.")

I have some of it written already, but I'm stuck at how to count the number of times each array element occurs. I have an idea that I'm going to need a method and a second array, but I've hit a wall:

```
public class NumOfOccurrIn7 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare scanner and array
        Scanner A = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter[] = new int[7];
        System.out.print("Please enter 7 numbers: ");

        //Populate initial array
        for(int t = 0; t < 7; t++) {
            counter[t] = A.nextInt();
        }

        //Process # of reoccurences and print results
        for(int t=0; t<7; t++) {


        }


        for(int t=0; t<7; t++) {
            System.out.print("Number " + counter[t] + " occurs " + x + 
                    " times./n");
        }

    }

    public static int CountOccurrance(int counter[]) {

    }

}
```

Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number 12 occurs twice, you don't want the output to print twice, so first you check if the number has already been processed. You do that by iterating over the array elements *before* `t`, and if one of them is the same as the current number, you don't print anything.

Next you check the rest of the array and count the number of times the current number occurs, then print the message.

```
// Process # of reoccurences and print results
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    boolean print = true;
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        if (counter[j] == counter[i]) {
            if (j < i) {
                print = false;
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (print) {
        System.out.println("Number " + counter[i] +
                           " occurs " + count + " times.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now that I see this (and the other helpful comment) it seems simpler than what I was trying to come up with. Bit of a bad habit of mine!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections::frequency` to count the occurrences e.g.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = { 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 5, 7, 8, 4, 9 };
        List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(nums).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(list);
        for (int n : set) {
            System.out.println("Frequency of " + n + " is " + Collections.frequency(list, n));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Frequency of 1 is 3
Frequency of 2 is 2
Frequency of 3 is 1
Frequency of 4 is 2
Frequency of 5 is 2
Frequency of 6 is 1
Frequency of 7 is 1
Frequency of 8 is 1
Frequency of 9 is 1
```

Another example of how you can count the duplicates is:

```
int[] nums = { 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 5, 7, 8, 4, 9 };
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
boolean duplicatesFound = false;
for (int n : nums) {
    if (map.get(n) == null) {
        map.put(n, 1);
    } else {
        map.put(n, map.get(n) + 1);
        duplicatesFound = true;
    }
}
if (duplicatesFound) {
    System.out.println("Duplicates are as follows:");
    map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " has occurred " + e.getValue() + " times."));
} else {
    System.out.println("There are no duplicates in the list");
}
```

**[Update]**

**Yet another solution (Thanks, @Andreas for the suggestion):**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = { 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6, 5, 7, 8, 4, 9 };
        Map<Integer, Long> frequencyMap = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n, Collectors.counting()));
        frequencyMap.forEach((n, count) -> {
            System.out.println("Frequency of " + n + " is " + count);
        });
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Frequency of 1 is 3
Frequency of 2 is 2
Frequency of 3 is 1
Frequency of 4 is 2
Frequency of 5 is 2
Frequency of 6 is 1
Frequency of 7 is 1
Frequency of 8 is 1
Frequency of 9 is 1
```

Comment: How can `map.get(n) == 0` ever be true?

Comment: Why do `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` when you have `Collectors.toList()`?

Comment: The second part is a nice _O(n)_ solution. Since you can easily do an _O(n)_ solution with streams using `groupingBy()` and `counting()`, why would you show a bad _O(n²)_ solution by using `frequency()`?

Answer (score 2):

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int counter[] = new int[7];

        System.out.print("Please enter 7 numbers: ");

        for (int t = 0; t < 7; t++) {
            counter[t] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        int[] occurrances = new int[counter.length];

        label:

        for (int t = 0; t < counter.length; t++) {
            int counterValue = counter[t];

            for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
                if (counterValue == counter[i]) {
                    continue label;
                }
            }

            occurrances[t] = 1;

            for (int j = 0; j < counter.length; j++) {
                if (j == t) {
                    continue;
                }
                int other = counter[j];

                if (other == counterValue) {
                    occurrances[t]++;
                }
            }

            if (occurrances[t] > 0) {
                System.out.println("Number " + counter[t] + " occurs " + occurrances[t] + " times.");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: *"This uses just 2-d arrays"* I see no 2D arrays. I do see two 1D arrays.

Comment: If I enter the same number 7 times, e.g. `2 2 2 2 2 2 2`, the program will print the same message 7 times. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now that I see this (and the other helpful comment) it seems simpler than what I was trying to come up with. Bit of a bad habit of mine!

Comment: No worries man. This can definitely be beautified but it does the job for your requirements.

Comment: Jason, While the program works I'm not sure I fully understand the logic of how the occurrence counting for loop works. Could you please help me understand?

Comment: The occurrences array acts as a simple counter for the number of occurrences that exists for each number. The occurrences array is the same size as the counter array. Every time we loop through counter we loop through all previous counters from 0 to index - 1. This is so we can check if any previous numbers have been already counted, and if so, continue. We continue by using a **label**. The label just allows us to break out of the second for loop and continue the first for loop.